# How to change editing style for specific cell in tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a tableview where the editingstyle is .delete for all the cells. But I want to have some specific cells that doesnt have editingstyle (so that you can't swipe them, .none). Anyone have any suggestions for how to implement this?

I tried to write something like UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.none for that specific row but that didnt work.

Thanks in advance, Pontus

Comment: It'd be better to edit your question with some code that you've tried so we could help you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    private let arr = (1...10).map { "Item \($0)" }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return arr.count
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")
        
        cell?.textLabel?.text = arr[indexPath.row]

        return cell ?? UITableViewCell()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell.EditingStyle {
        if indexPath.row == 2 {//<- Your condition
            return .none
        } else {
            return .delete
        }
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
    
}
```

So the key is to use `editingStyleForRowAt` in order to change the style for a specific cell (or even multiple cells) (see the documentation for further reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614869-tableview).